# how to use NtCreateMutant(Zw) to create a mutex in C++

Tags: c++, mutex

I want to create a mutex with the kernel function `NtCreateMutant`.

I did it like this:

```
Handle hMutex;
NTSTATUS ntMutex = NtOpenMutant(&hMutex,MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS,false);
```

But this is the `NTSTATUS` value that is returned:

```
C0000024    STATUS_OBJECT_TYPE_MISMATCH
```

With the windows API `OpenMutex(..)`, it's working just fine...

```
HANDLE hMutex;
hMutex = OpenMutex(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, "Name");
```

Hope someone can explain me how to use the native function :)

So I want to do the same as this, but with native functions:

```
HANDLE hMutex;
hMutex = OpenMutex(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, "NameOfMyMutex");
if(hMutex == NULL)
{
    hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, "NameOfMyMutex");
}
else
{
    return FALSE;
}
```

I hope someone can help me with calling `NtOpenMutant` the right way.

Comment: Is there any good reason for using native function? It isn't portable, and neither recommended.

Comment: Yes easier to hide functions for debuggers.. you will have to use the native APIs to create your own sub to call it

Comment: Is there any good reason for hiding this to a debugger ? I mean, you can't produce a binary that can't be reverse-engineered anyway, and even if you can make it harder for someone to reverse-engineer it, doing so is probably overkill and not bug-proof.

Comment: As long as you use functions that "hide from the debugger", you'll have to find your own way to debug them.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please post more code? It's not entirely clear what's going on here just yet, but here are a few thoughts:

1) You start by saying you create your mutex with `NtCreateMutant`, but the code you posted is using `NtOpenMutant`. Please clarify exactly what you're actually doing here, preferably with a larger code snippet.

2) `NtCreateMutant` doesn't take 3 parameters, and `NtOpenMutant` does not take a boolean 3rd parameter:

```
+NTSTATUS SERVICECALL
+NtCreateMutant(OUT PHANDLE MutantHandle,
+               IN ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess,
+               IN POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes  OPTIONAL,
+               IN BOOLEAN InitialOwner);
+
+NTSTATUS SERVICECALL
+NtOpenMutant(OUT PHANDLE       MutantHandle,
+             IN  ACCESS_MASK       DesiredAccess,
+             IN  POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES    ObjectAttributes);
```

It's not clear which you intend to be using, but it would appear regardless of which you meant to use, you may be using it incorrectly.

If you really mean to use `NtOpenMutant`, it would seem that your third parameter needs to be an OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES structure, defined [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557749%28VS.85%29.aspx) to be:

```
typedef struct _OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES {
  ULONG           Length;
  HANDLE          RootDirectory;
  PUNICODE_STRING ObjectName;
  ULONG           Attributes;
  PVOID           SecurityDescriptor;
  PVOID           SecurityQualityOfService;
}  OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES, *POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES;
```

Keep in mind that the Nt* functions are not exact mirrors of the public and documented Windows API. This seems to be where you're experiencing your issues.

Comment: Hey thanks i want to avoid the more times execution of my exe file.

atm i am using OpenMutex to check if the mutex is already create -> termiante process else i create my mutex with CreateMutex API. 
So now i want to use the native functions of these APIs.
Thats why i am asking if someone could give me a direction to setup the native call right.

http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/Mutant/NtOpenMutant.html

I have my information from this website; there are 3 params written.

Comment: So i have to fill the struct with the right stuff... could someone show me the right direction? or do i have to reverse the call to OpenMutex

Comment: and thanks for this :) its explaining how to fill the struct :) 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557749%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Simon: Yes, the link for `NtOpenMutex` takes 3 parameters, as I stated, but it wasn't clear whether you were intending to use `NtOpenMutex` or `NtCreateMutex` (which takes 4 params). But as your link shows (as well as the interface I posted), the third parameter is an `_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES` struct and not a boolean. Your input of `false` is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you want is to mimmic the code you posted with winapi,
i.e. to try to open, and if not exist create.

I recommend you to look at ReactOs and look for the implementation of
OpenMutex and CreateMutex

This should give you the answer of how to "translate" the winapi functions to Native ones